# Why socket.send in python doesn't work?

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I am trying to send the data from python flask server on raspberry pi to nodemcu client using WiFi connection. I established a TCP connection successfully. However, the sock.send is not working under particular function. If i use sock.send outside this function it works fine. Can someone review my code.

```
def flask():
    connection() #This function establish the connection successfully. I have not included the content of function just for simplicity. No problem with this part.
    sock.send('thanks for connecting') #This works fine.
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='Templates')
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
    @app.route('/message')
    def msg():
        a = request.args.get('a') #This the variable obtained from web page using j Query. I want to send this value to nodemcu client. 
        sock.send(a) #This is NOT WORKING
        print(a) #But the value is printed on python terminal.
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable `sock`?

Comment: I declared that as a global.

Comment: sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is it getting an error?

Comment: No there is no error. But the message is not sent from flask.

Comment: sock.send('thanks for connecting') in second  line is sent from flask and received on client successfully. But sock.send(a) is not sent.